# How to maintain bottom space when image and growing label are being used in parallel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have 3 elements, imageview, label and a view. I want to maintain the eqaul space (15) for bottom view. Layout is as :
Imageview then label and at the bottom, there is a view. I have defined the top constraints of the view >=15 from the imageview, 84 from label but I want to push down the view when the label grows beyond the imgeview. Now what is happening the view is pushing down when the lable gets on new line and there is more than 15pt space between label and the bottom view which I don't want.
[image]

Comment: try adding both bottom constraint (from image and label) with bottom view >= 15. It'll show error in storyboard but will be feasible at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to put the image view and label in a horizontal stack view, with Alignment set to Top:

[image]

[image]

The stack view is constrained at 16-pts Top / Leading / Trailing, and 15-pts to the "blue view."

At run-time, with different amounts of text in the label:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, @DonMag, to achieve this by making use of stack view is the best approach as of now, only one problem in using stack view we can't give top constraints to the label as to push down to 15pt

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh - you want the top edge of the label to be 15-pts lower than the top edge of the image view? Or, do you want the label vertically centered on the image view (if the text is short)?

Comment: I want top edge of the label to be 15-pts lower than the top edge of the image view

Comment: select the label... select Embed in UIView... constrain the label 15-pts Top, Zero Leading / Trailing / Bottom

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the screenshot for storyboard.]

[image: This is from simulator running app with label smaller than image.]

[image: This is from simulator running app with label greater than image pushing bottom view.]

1. This is the screenshot for storyboard.
2. This is from simulator running app with label smaller than image.
3. This is from simulator running app with label greater than image pushing bottom view.

Comment: you have understood the problem exaclty

Comment: added comment on your question for the solution. check that please